# conversion in c

Tags: c, functional-programming

I'm new to C and I need to write a function in c which converts an integer to a string in the specified base and print it.

If I were given an input value of 1234 (base 10) it should return 2322 (base 8).

Here is the code structure I'm currently working on:

```
void int2ascii(int value, int base){
    int a=0;
    if (value > base) {
         a = a + int2char(value);     //recursive case
         int2ascii(value/base, base); //base case
    }
    printf("%s\n",a);
 }
```

The program won't run, can someone enlighten me?
Thanks

Comment: Why isn't your method returning anything?

Comment: Trying to figure out how it *could* run.

Comment: Also, `a` is not a string in your program.

Comment: Is it not compiling or is it crashing?

Comment: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_517.html

Comment: @dcc - I think we all know that there are library routines for this, but the OP wants to do it as a learning experience.

Comment: @Hot Licks int2char is another method that convert int to chars.

Comment: Generally, when you convert a binary number to radix X you produce the least-significant digit by doing "modulo X" and adding the numeric value for the character zero.  Eg, `char digit = (value % base) + '0';`

Comment: @Caim O  It is crashing.

Comment: Hint: There's no need to calculate the character to print until just before you print it.  And if that logic is inside the `if` that will do recursion the last digit will not get formatted.

Comment: Get a pencil and paper and walk through your algorithm for maybe the value 1234.  "Execute" the algorithm on paper and write down each result.

Comment: Numbers do not have digits or bits; they *may* be *represented* as sequence of digits or bits (or in full words, or as expressions, e.g. 11 = eleven = 9+2). You probably should handle 1234 as a *string*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - So you want him to convert the number from string to int and back to string??  Why???

Comment: Because `1234` (base ten) is the *same number* as `02322` (octal).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - But the stated problem isn't to parse a decimal value.

Answer (score 5):

## Analysis of your program

I noted first off that `a` is declared `int`, but it was being passed to `printf` with `%s` as the format specifier. `%s` designates the associated argument will be a string, which `a` is not. The result will be undefined behavior, and is ***a possible cause for your crash***.

You do not specify what `int2char()` does, but let's assume that it converts a numeric "digit" into a corresponding `char` value. With that in mind, let us suppose its implementation is similar to:

```
int int2char(int d) {
    return "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[d];
}
```

In your code, you pass `value` to `int2char()`. In my hypothetical implementation, this would cause out-of-bounds access of the array, and thus undefined behavior. This is indicates a logic error, and ***another possible cause for your crash***.

I note that if `value` is less than `base`, `a` remains `0`. Probably, you really mean to compute a value for `a` even when `value` is less than `base`. This indicates another logic error.

## Base conversion

The number d<sub>K</sub>d<sub>K-1</sub> .. d<sub>0</sub>, where each d<sub>i</sub> is in (0 .. 9), is a short form for ∑d<sub>i</sub>×10<sup>i</sup>. To discover the base 10 digits of a number N, the process is:

> d<sub>i</sub> = <sub>⌊</sub>N / 10<sup>i</sup><sub>⌋</sub> mod 10

But, as it turns out, you can replace 10 with some other base number to compute the digits for a number in that base:

> d<sub>i</sub> = <sub>⌊</sub>N / B<sup>i</sup><sub>⌋</sub> mod B

In your code, the recursive call that divides by the base represents the first part of the calculation. However, in your calculation of `a`, you were missing the "mod" part of the calculation.

## Solution 1

Assuming base is from 2 to 36, and that your `int2char(d)` does something more or less as illustrated earlier:

```
void int2ascii(int value, int base){
    int a=0;
    a = a + int2char(value%base);
    if (value > base) {
         int2ascii(value/base, base);
    }
    printf("%c",a);
}
```

Because you are not passing `a` into your recursive call, you can only use it to store the current digit to be printed. So, move the code to store the value in `a` out of the `if` check, since you always want a sensible value to print at the end. The digit in `a` is in the radix `base`, so you need the modulus result to get the right digit value. Since `a` represents a character, change the format string to match, and remove the `\n` so that all the digits end up on the same line.

## Solution 2

The first solution is an attempt to leave most of your original code intact. Since `a` is initialized to `0`, the extra addition does not make it incorrect. But, since the print doesn't happen until the very end, the value doesn't really need to be stored at all, and can be calculated at the point you actually want to print it. With that in mind, the program can be simplified to:

```
void int2ascii(int value, int base){
    if (value > base) {
         int2ascii(value/base, base);
    }
    printf("%c",int2char(value%base));
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why using % in the base case?

Comment: If you think about a number like "32", to get the digit "2", you need "32 % 10". Then, divide by 10 to get "3", and "3 % 10" is "3".

Comment: The point is, you might be able to avoid using % at the very end for the most significant digit, but using it for that case doesn't affect correctness, and using it for all the other cases is required in order to compute the correct digit.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

char *int2ascii_aux(int n, int base, char *s){
    //base {x| 2 <= x <= 36 }
    static const char *table = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if(n){
        *--s = table[n % base];
        return int2ascii_aux(n/base, base, s);
    } else {
        return s;
    }
}

char *int2ascii(int n, int base){
    //base {x| 2<= x <= 36 }
    static char s[sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT+1];
    if(n <= 0){
        *s = '0';
        return s;
    }
    if(base < 2 ||  base > 36){
        *s = '\0';
        return s;
    }
    return int2ascii_aux(n, base, s + sizeof(s) -1);
}

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", int2ascii(1234, 8));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of the code or what you're doing that the OP isn't?

Comment: @HotLicks `int a=0;..a = a + int2char(value);..printf("%s\n",a);` Implementation impossible in this logic.

Comment: But what does he learn from your code (other that to search around for someone's code to copy)?

Comment: Is this possible with out using a helper method?

Comment: @HotLicks It is going to be implemented on their own to learn some difference.

Comment: @RadScorpius - yes, you only need modulus and integer division

Comment: @RadScorpius I think it's useless in the current interface if it is necessary to convert the string to not only output to the screen.